# How to distinguish paths and params of routes in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have an express application with the following routes:

```
// Get category by id
innerRouter.get('/:id', categoriesController.getById)

// Get all categories along with their subcategories
innerRouter.get('/withSubcategories', categoriesController.getAllWithSubcategories)
```

The problem is that express doesn't seem to distinguish between the two, for example with this request:

`http://localhost:3000/api/categories/withSubcategories`

Express will actually invoke `categoriesController.getById` and not `categoriesController.getAllWithSubcategories`.

I know i can create a single route and then check for `req.params.id`, but i want to believe that there's a more elegant way of doing this, is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Express is sensitive to the order with which you define routes, so moving `/withSubcategories` above `/:id` will solve the issue. However, you should probably move `/:id` to something like `/category/:id` since having a match-all in the root path is inadvisable.

Comment: I changed the order and it works, about moving the `:id` to `category/:id`, these two routes already sits in a `app.use('/category', myRouter)`, i just wanted to keep it a simple REST api

Comment: @TwoHorses - When you use `/:id` you then have a responsibility in the internals of your app to make sure that no `id` value will EVER conflict with the other paths you use.  If the ids are something you control entirely, that may not be hard to do, but if they were, for example, a user-defined category name, then they very well could conflict.  Using `/:id` and `/somethingElse` as routes is asking for trouble unless you carefullly control the id values to never conflict with your static paths.

Comment: @jfriend00 then what is a good solution? I just want to keep my API as simple as possible

Comment: @TwoHorses - Use a unique path prefix in front of `/:id`that isn't used by anything else.  I don't know the overall layout of your app and URL structure to have enough info to know what specifically to suggest.  URL API design needs to see the overall layout of everything you're doing to know how to best slot each item in place.